# How to ask user again to register for RemoteNotifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My application uses the push notifications, I am asking the user to register for push notifications at the time of Application launch. Everything works fine if the user taps the 'allow' button. But what if the user presses "Dont' Allow" by mistake ? , I want to pop-up the message again in the device, to ask the user to get registered with the push notifications. How to ask the user again to get registered ?

Comment: How do you know that the user didn't press "Don't Allow" on purpose?  Spamming me to enable Push Notifications would result in the app being removed from my device immediately.

Comment: I mean by either way, user presses "Don't Allow " by mistake or purposely. I want to display that Notification again.

Comment: Either way your app would immediately be deleted from my device if you did that to me.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't receive an answer or why this question was closed. The answer to your questions is very simple: You cannot ask the user again! As apple says: "Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored...". It's not about what is the correct way, you just can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user cancels, or mistakenly presses 'Don't Allow' for the Notification alert, you can easily Alert them later to go into Settings.app and 'Enable' Push Notifications for it if thats what they're trying to do.

Use a storage mechanism to determine if the user has accepted the Alert or not via `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`.. and `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.. which you can check for later on and route them to the Settings.app to enable Notifications.

Hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 3):

[Troubleshooting Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

**Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS**

The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back on.

Comment: Hi @Nit, thanks for the reply. I have gone through the document now. And setting system clock hint will help me in future.That seems to be so secure, but I was wondering what if the user presses the "Don't Allow" by mistake. It ain't a problem for a user to reinstall the application again. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The most correct way from user experience point of view is to provide your user a choice - to allow push notifications or not to allow from Setting section of your App. You really can't be sure that user's "No, thanks" was pressed by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the user open push notification in Settings
You need do nothing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it, is at the first to ask the user to register for push notifications, afterwards you just popup a message each while asking the user, that if he/she didn't register for push notifications with an option to register and call the delegate on OK.